# Error when creating aws emr default-roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, elastic-map-reduce

I'm trying to create a cluster using aws cli emr command. However, I can't seem to be able to create-default-roles needed before calling `aws emr create-cluster`

```
$ aws emr create-default-roles

A client error (NoSuchEntity) occurred when calling the GetRole operation: Unknown
```

I have made sure that my user has the following permissions:

```
IAMFullAccess - AWS Managed policy
AmazonElasticMapReduceforEC2Role - AWS Managed policy
AmazonElasticMapReduceFullAccess - AWS Managed policy
```

Any tips? Is there a place where I can just copy the roles json and create them manually?

The reason I started to do this is because when I run `aws emr create-cluster` it returns a `cluster-id`. But when that `cluster-id` is queries it state is set to terminated with the error: `EMR service role arn:aws:iam::141703095098:role/EMR_DefaultRole is invalid`

Comment: Does your [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) work correctly for other commands? For example, can you do `aws s3 ls`? If you launch a cluster via the console, it will create the roles for you, too.

Comment: Ues it works, `create-cluster` works too but it terminates with an error `EMR service role arn:aws:iam::141703095098:role/EMR_DefaultRole is invalid`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I DID manage to add these roles using the console by going to:

**My Security Credentials > Roles > Create New Role**

First Role with the following properties:

```
name: EMR_DefaultRole
policy: AmazonElasticMapReduceRole
```

Second Role with the following properties:

```
name: EMR_EC2_DefaultRole
policy: AmazonElasticMapReduceforEC2Role
```

Unfortunately I didn't get the command-line to work, but I suspect I might be something to do with my local setup.

Comment: I'm actually running into this problem as well. I'll try as you suggested in the console. Could this be a cli bug?

Comment: I was able to create a cluster once I added these roles via the console.

Comment: @bblincoe yea I recommend starting a fresh terminal session and trying CLI again before trying the console solution

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with the console. With the client this worked:

```
# upgrade aws cli (can't hurt)
pip install --upgrade --user awscli

# aws configure process if you haven't (look it up)

# delete all the defunct shizzles
aws iam remove-role-from-instance-profile --instance-profile-name EMR_EC2_DefaultRole \
    --role-name EMR_EC2_DefaultRole
aws iam delete-instance-profile \
    --instance-profile-name EMR_EC2_DefaultRole
aws iam detach-role-policy \
  --role-name EMR_EC2_DefaultRole \
  --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonElasticMapReduceforEC2Role
aws iam delete-role --role-name EMR_EC2_DefaultRole
aws iam detach-role-policy --role-name EMR_DefaultRole \
    --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonElasticMapReduceRole
aws iam delete-role --role-name EMR_DefaultRole

# now re-create them
aws emr create-default-roles
```

Note if you have attached policies, you might have to go into the console and delete them or find the appropriate aws cli command.

Source (our product is buggy and our role system is cumbersome, but if you buy premium support we'll tell you the workarounds):
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-default-role-invalid/